# Storing JSON in HBase and query by Id

Tags: hbase

Am I correct of storing JSON data in HBase?

```
 put 'messages', 123, 'cf:json', '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

Basically, I need to query it by ID, which is 123 in my example. And JSON is variable length string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no problem storing JSON in a cell value. Cell sizes of up to 5M are still reasonable. Generally speaking though it is recommended to keep key and column sizes small (http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#keysize) and  JSON, while being more compact than XML,  is still a wasteful format (vs. binary JSON, Thrift, Avro, MessagePack etc.). if you stay with JSON you might need to consider making the column family compressed

Comment: Hi! The client uses plain JSON, so if I use BSON or any other binary format, it would bring additional overhead on conversion. Maybe it's better to add column family compression instead?

Comment: What size of tables are you talking about?

Comment: if your JSONs aren't too big it shouldn't be a problem. You can start with that and add a compressed column family (and migrate) later

Comment: If we need to query within json string like where foo='bar' in above example can we do that in hbase

Comment: @ruby, we have a similar requirement and were thinking whether to put entire json in a single column or create a new column family and store each key of json as column.